# __init__ module not getting copied when installing with setup.py

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

I have the following structure setup for project

```
/docs
    releaseNotes.rst
MANIFEST.in
/pySan
    __init__.py
    __init__.pyc
    /torrent
        __init__.py 
        components.py
    utils.py
    utils.pyc
setup.py
VERSION
```

but when I install the `__init__.py` inside `torrent` folder is not getting copied.

It is installed in  `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pySan` and the `setup.py` is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from os import path

v = open(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'VERSION'))
VERSION = v.readline().strip()
v.close()

setup(
    name='pySan',
    version=VERSION,
    author='Ciasto Piekarz',
    author_email='Ciasto_piekarz@gmail.com',
    packages=['pySan', 'pySan/torrent'],
    data_files = ['VERSION'],
    license='LICENSE',
    description='Package is a collection of commonly used code for all my tools',
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
packages=['pySan', 'pySan/torrent'],
```

You need to use package syntax:

```
packages=['pySan', 'pySan.torrent'],
```

Comment: This answer helped me but I am using find_package:
`from setuptools import setup, find_packages`
...
`packages=find_packages(include=['mypackage','mypackage.data'])`
The dot made de difference to me.

Answer (score 0):

Along with providing a packages value in the correct format make sure that you're also running "setup.py build" not "setup.py build_ext" which will only build extensions and not copy over any .py files.